# 404 Custom error IIS setup

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, custom-errors

Who likes a head scratcher!

We have 2 identical servers sitting behind a load balancer using sticky session to direct the user to the correct server. Both are running the same version of the web app but only one of them is showing our custom 404 error page.

I have compared all IIS and web.config settings and have not found any that do not match. I have even temporarily used the working web.config on the second server but to no avail.

Our setup:
Win2008 IIS7 - 64 bit
Classic mode
Application_Error

- GetLastError()
- Send Email
- Server.Transfer system.web/customErrors

As I said custom error displays on the first server, but not on the second, so all ideas are welcome.

Comment: So, you've installed a handler so that *all* web requests are treated as IsapiModule? Normally 404 won't even enter Application_Error.

Comment: Yeah thats right, we use the aspnet_isapi handler to mimic IIS6 wildcard script mapping

Comment: Not entering the Application_Error handler is the only thing I can think of. Once there, the Server.Transfer call should get them to your error page -- I've never heard of it having different behavior on different machines.  Things that I'd (re)check are the IIS aspnet_isapi handler and that the custom error page and Global.asax page exist on the second server.